# How to customize deserialize a object that contains a field of its own in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, abstract-class, abstract-syntax-tree

Take a abstract syntax tree for example, a binary expression will somewhat looks like the following

```
class BinaryExpression : ExpressionSyntaxNode
{
    private ExpressionSyntaxNode left;
    private ExpressionSyntaxNode right;
    private Operator optr;
}
```

If I want to do a customize serialization, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx, I will need to implement ISerializable and have something like this

```
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    Left.GetObjectData(info, context);
    Right.GetObjectData(info, context);
    Optr.GetObjectData(info, context);
}
```

Now I am very confused how should I do deserialization, because it does not have a **SetObjectData** function which otherwsie could have allowed me to do

```
public virtual void SetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    Left = Left.SetObjectData(info, context);
    Right = Right.SetObjectData(info, context);
    Optr = Optr.SetObjectData(info, context);
}
```

and I do not know how the special constructor can help in this case cos the exact type I will be deserializing those field (left, right and optr) into is unknown at compile time. ExpressionSynatxNode is also only a abstract class so what's the solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling `SetObjectData()` and `GetObjectData()` on the values of the fields inside your `ISerializable` type, you need to add the values themselves to the serialization stream via [`SerializationInfo.AddValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.addvalue.aspx), then fetch the deserialized values out with [`GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getvalue.aspx):

```
[Serializable]
class BinaryExpression : ExpressionSyntaxNode, ISerializable
{
    private ExpressionSyntaxNode left;
    private ExpressionSyntaxNode right;
    private Operator optr;

    public BinaryExpression(ExpressionSyntaxNode left, ExpressionSyntaxNode right, Operator optr)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.optr = optr;
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    protected BinaryExpression(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        left = (ExpressionSyntaxNode)info.GetValue("left", typeof(ExpressionSyntaxNode));
        right = (ExpressionSyntaxNode)info.GetValue("right", typeof(ExpressionSyntaxNode));
        optr = (Operator)info.GetValue("optr", typeof(Operator));
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue("left", left);
        info.AddValue("right", right);
        info.AddValue("optr", optr);
    }

    #endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0} {1} {2})", left.ToString(), optr.ToString(), right.ToString());
    }
}
```

To extend the example, a simple class hierarchy of `ISerializable` objects of type `ExpressionSyntaxNode` might look as follows.  Note the chaining of streaming constructors and calls to `GetObjectData()` from derived to base type:

```
[Serializable]
abstract class ExpressionSyntaxNode : ISerializable
{
    protected ExpressionSyntaxNode()
    {
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    protected ExpressionSyntaxNode(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }

    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}

[Serializable]
abstract class ValueExpression<T> : ExpressionSyntaxNode, ISerializable where T : IConvertible
{
    T value;

    public T Value { get { return value; } }

    public ValueExpression(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue("value", value);
    }

    protected ValueExpression(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        this.value = (T)info.GetValue("value", typeof(T));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        return value.ToString();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class BooleanExpression : ValueExpression<bool>, ISerializable
{
    public BooleanExpression(bool value) : base(value) { }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    protected BooleanExpression(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}

[Serializable]
public enum Operator
{
    And,
    Or
}
```

Test example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var expression = new BinaryExpression(
            new BinaryExpression(new BooleanExpression(false), new BooleanExpression(true), Operator.And), 
            new BinaryExpression(new BooleanExpression(true), new BooleanExpression(false), Operator.Or), 
            Operator.Or);

        Debug.WriteLine("Initial expression: ");
        Debug.WriteLine(expression); // "((False And True) Or (True Or False))"

        if (expression.ToString() != "((False And True) Or (True Or False))")
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var binary = BinaryFormatterHelper.ToBinary(expression);

        var expression2 = BinaryFormatterHelper.FromBinary<BinaryExpression>(binary);

        Debug.WriteLine("Deserialized expression: ");
        Debug.WriteLine(expression2);

        if (expression.ToString() != expression2.ToString())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Deserialized and original expressions are identical");
        }
    }
}

public static partial class BinaryFormatterHelper
{
    public static byte[] ToBinary<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T FromBinary<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            if (obj is T)
                return (T)obj;
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: based on your answer does that mean I have no way to use the constructor to deserialize the BinaryExpression obj?

Comment: @user1935724 - yes, it's not intended to be used that way.  The serializer itself calls the constructor and passes in a `SerializationInfo` populated with the field values for that particular object, extracted from the serialization stream.  Since the nested objects will naturally contain different field values internally, a different `SerializationInfo` is required.when deserializing them.